# Are there five or six reasons why Parshas Tzitzis was added to Shema?

Tags: tzitzis, shema, tractate-brachot, parashat-shelach

Berachos 12b:

> פָּרָשַׁת צִיצִית מִפְּנֵי מָה קְבָעוּהָ? אָמַר רַבִּי יְהוּדָה בַּר חֲבִיבָא, מִפְּנֵי שֶׁיֵּשׁ בָּהּ חֲמִשָּׁה דְּבָרִים: מִצְוַת צִיצִית, יְצִיאַת מִצְרַיִם, עוֹל מִצְוֹת, וְדַעַת מִינִים, הִרְהוּר עֲבֵירָה, וְהִרְהוּר עֲבוֹדָה זָרָה
>
> Why did they establish the section of Tzitzis [to be said with Shema]? R' Yehudah bar Chaviva said, "Because it has in it five things: The mitzvah of Tzitzis, leaving Mitzraim, the yoke of Mitzvos, opinions of heretics, thoughts of sin, and thoughts of idolatry."

Um, that's six things, not five.

At first I thought "thoughts of sin" and "thoughts of idolatry" were counted as one item, but the Gemara proceeds to note where in the passage each of these things are discussed, and each of them gets its own passuk.

How, then, is this to be understood as five items?

Comment: Apparently there are some texts that read "six". See note ה in the mesoret hashas [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=12b&format=pdf)

Answer (score 7):

This passage also appears in [Yalkut Shimoni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yalkut_Shimoni), and in that version there are indeed only five things. Number 4, "opinions of heretics" in your translation, does not appear. The supporting verse cited in the Talmud for it also does not appear:

> פרשת ציצית מפני מה קבעוה בק"ש מפני שיש בה חמשה דברים מצות ציצית ויציאת מצרים ועול מצות והרהור עבירה והרהור אלילים בשלמא הני תלתא מפרשי אלא עבירה ואלילים מנלן דתניא אחרי לבבכם זה הרהור עבירה ואחרי עיניכם זה הרהור אלילים

This question was in fact asked by [R. Samuel Eidels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maharsha) in his commentary to the Talmud there. He first notes the parallel passage in the Yalkut Shimoni, but then offers a suggestion how we can even understand the Talmud's text as is. He suggests that Number 5 and Number 6, "thoughts of sin" and "thoughts of idolatry" in your translation, are essentially the same thing. The Talmud thus means that there are five *discrete* things:

> מפני שיש בה ה' דברים כו'. קאמר ה' דברים וחשיב ששה ובגירסת ילקוט לא חשיב מינות ול"ג דתניא אחרי לבבכם זה מינות וכה"א אמר נבל וגו' ע"ש והיינו מינות היינו הרהור ע"ג ונראה ליישב גירסת כל הספרים דמינות היינו כופר במציאות כדמייתי אמר נבל בלבו אין אלהים והרהור ע"ג היינו דמשתף שם שמים ודבר אחר וצריך לומר לפי זה דהרהור עבירה והרהור ע"ג חשיב כחדא ודו"ק

I would also suggest, though I have no source for this, that there is no contradiction to begin with. The Talmud's question was why the parshah of **tzitzit** was included in Shema. The Talmud already knows that it contains the mitzvah of tzitzit, and it is seeking *additional* value in this parshah. The answer to that is that this parshah contains five *additional* things. Thus, the first thing in the list, tzitzit, is not part of the "five things".