# Why does Rashi explain where yoke of Mitzvos is discussed in Parshas Tzitzis?

Tags: rashi, tzitzis, shema, tractate-brachot

Berachos 12b:

> פָּרָשַׁת צִיצִית מִפְּנֵי מָה קְבָעוּהָ? אָמַר רַבִּי יְהוּדָה בַּר חֲבִיבָא, מִפְּנֵי שֶׁיֵּשׁ בָּהּ חֲמִשָּׁה דְּבָרִים: מִצְוַת צִיצִית, יְצִיאַת מִצְרַיִם, עוֹל מִצְוֹת, וְדַעַת מִינִים, הִרְהוּר עֲבֵירָה, וְהִרְהוּר עֲבוֹדָה זָרָה
>
> Why did they establish the section of Tzitzis [to be said with Shema]? R' Yehudah bar Chaviva said, "Because it has in it five things: The mitzvah of Tzitzis, leaving Mitzraim, the yoke of Mitzvos, opinions of heretics, thoughts of sin, and thoughts of idolatry."

Rashi on "yoke of Mitzvos" writes:

> עול מצות – ועשיתם את כל מצותי:
>
> "Yoke of Mitzvos" – "And you should do all My mitzvos."

The Gemara is about to give a source for everything on this list. Why does Rashi feel the need to give the same source the Gemara does in two lines, and why for this item specifically?

Comment: Rashi doesn't even give precisely the same source. The gemara's source is "וראיתם אותו וזכרתם את כל מצות ה'".

Answer (score 6):

In the parallel passage in Yalkut Shimoni (which I cited [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/111012/13438)), no verses are given for the three that are obvious. In fact, R. Refael Nota Nosson Rabinowitz ([Dikdukei Sofrim](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38512&st=&pgnum=137)) presents this comment of Rashi as evidence that there was a different Talmudic version which did not have this:

> וכן נר' מרש"י שלא היה בגירסתו שהביא מעצמו הקרא המאוחר ועשיתם את כו' והוא באמת פירוש יפה יותר מפסו' וזכרתם המובא לפנינו דכאן הוא זכירה ועשייה שהוא העול מצות